# Hardware issue ? zfs scrub always repair

Tags: memory, zfs

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I have a curious problem with an old Tyan server motherboard and ZFS.

In short, I can run `zfs scrub`every hour, it always repair checksums, with no further error.

I ran memtest86 all nignt long with no error (16GB ECC memory)

I ran `smartctl -t long /dev/ada{0,1,2}` showhing no error neither

But scrubbing keep showing checksum errors.

Thanks for any clue

Xav

Comment: I would first check cables (if possible by replacing them) and then for the controllers. Do you use a PCIe/PCI controller or an onboard controller? Are the errors on specific drives or on all drives?

Answer (score 2):

This means that either a) you're writing bad sectors to the disk, or b) you're reading bad sectors back.  If it's a small number of sectors being corrected each time, my experience is that it's a bad controller or driver.

That is all assuming you don't get console errors.

Reasoning?  Well ... if it's the drives, they generally are smart enough to report their errors (at least most of them).  If it's the cables, generally you'll be getting checksum errors from the driver on your console.  You've mostly eliminated memory, so...  You're left with controllers and drivers.

Luckily with ZFS, you can "try" the drives in another machine without too much hassle, usually.

Comment: Thanks,


I'll suspect the controllers too, while it dosen't want to load its BIOS for the last reboot (Two Adaptec 1210 cards)


Is ZFS smart enough to recognise the pool if I blindly move the cables to the motherboard's controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I'll suspect the controller too, while it dosen't want to load its BIOS for the last reboot (Two Adaptec 1210 cards)

Is ZFS smart enough to recognise the pool if I blindly move the cables to the motherboard's controller ?

Comment: Hrm.  That's another question.  :).

Comment: So... generally, yes.  I don't know your adaptec cards or how you configured them, however.  If zfs doesn't recognize them it will be due to an adaptec configuration on them.  What you can do is move the drives one-at-a-time and re-add/resilver them each time before moving the next drive.

Comment: Or you could move them split in half (or thirds, if you have more redundancy), so that each set of drives is enough to run on its own. One remains in the old system, one is used in the new system.